# Passport create multi session in my database

Tags: angular, session, sails.js, passport.js

I’m confronted to a weird situation using an API made with sailsJS.

So when I use postman to login, passport create one session in DB and everything works fine.

But when I use my app made with Angular2 and do the same request to my API, passport generate many sessions in my DB …

Here is my Code :
**Login - SailsJS**

```js
  login: (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      if ((err) || (!user)) {
        return res.send({
          message: info.message,
          user: user
        });
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        return res.send({
          message: info.message,
          user: user
        });
      });

    })(req, res);
  },
```

**PassPort Conf - SailsJS**

```js
function findById(id, fn) {
  User.findOne(id).then(function (user) {
    if (!user) return fn("User Not Found", null) ;
    return fn(null, user);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("err",err) ;
    return fn(err, null);
  });
}

passport.serializeUser( (user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser( (id, done) => {
  findById(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err)
      user = null;
    return done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function (email, password, done) {

    User.findOne({email: email}, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect email.'});
      }

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
        if (!res)
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Invalid Password'
          });
        let returnUser = {
          id: user.id,
          email: user.email
        };
        return done(null, returnUser, {
          message: 'Logged In Successfully'
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

**Calling the api - Angular2**

```js
private _headers = new Headers();
private _options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: this._headers,
  withCredentials: true
});
login(email, password): Observable < any > {
  return this._http
    .post(this._url + 'login', {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }, this._options)
    .map(
      (res: any) => {
        let user = JSON.parse(res._body).user;
        if (user) {
          this.isLogged = true;
          localStorage.setItem('User', JSON.stringify(user));
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally add the "saveUninitialized" to false in my express-session configuration.

This parameter set to true forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store.  [Documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

So now, as long as req.session is not updated by passport, the session is not stored.